# android making a music app accessing the sdcard for music data help/ info

Tags: java, android, media, audio

So I am building this music app which so far just scans a specific folder inside the SD card. This returns the paths and then plays them.

A few hours ago I got informed that there is like a media file database in the android system so

1. I am wondering if this media file database is there and if I can in some way get it to return all audio files with a path and then play them
2. I am wondering if there is any way I can get album cover and artist information from this database also

I have been reseraching on `MediaStore` and `MediaScan` connection but i can't find any thing so I need some sample code please.

Answer (score 1):

You did say please... so maybe something like the following links. They might not have everything you want, but they all contain information that is relevant to your project. When searching or trying to find a solution, don't give up when you can't find exactly what you need. As long as something has some relevant information, take it and use it. It's how developers/pirates work.

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/

or

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/android-%E2%80%93-videomusic-player-sample-take-2/

Or even on a SO page

[Android mp3 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139490/android-mp3-player)

You might want to check the references as well:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Comment: hey ty for the answer but i have already took a look at alle of this links before i made this post but ty any why as fare as i can see the first and second link uses a specified / userinputed folder for the music / video input


sry for the long replay time